# How to set timeout for Api call using retrofit in flutter?

Tags: flutter, retrofit2, connection-timeout

Where we can set timeout in below code?
As you can see I am using retrofit for api call.

Dio Object

```
class DioObject{
  static Dio  getDio(){
    debugPrint("Bearer:- ${PrefHelper().pref?.getString(PrefHelper.AUTHORIZATION)}");
    final dio = Dio(); // Provide a dio instance
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] =
    "Bearer ${PrefHelper().pref?.getString(PrefHelper.AUTHORIZATION)}"; // config your dio headers globally
    dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] =
    "application/json;charset=UTF-8"; // config your dio headers globally
    
    return dio;
  }

}
```

Api call

```
final client = RestClient(DioObject.getDio());
  
var response = await client.xyz();
```

Rest API

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: "*****/api")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _RestClient;

 

 @GET("/UserAccessPoints/")
  Future<CommonResponse> xyz();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way you added your custom headers, or doing it all at once with a `BaseOptions` object

```
  final dio = Dio();

  //Dio Options
  dio.options = BaseOptions(
    contentType: 'application/json',
    connectTimeout: 4000,
    sendTimeout: 4000,
    receiveTimeout: 10000,
    headers : ...
  );
```